# Plot legend with subscript and insert stored value in R

Tags: r, plot

Trying to add a legend to my plot, which should display some fitting parameters I've calculated earlier, subscripts AND a new line for every parameter, but I can't seem to make a legend that works with e.g. `substitute()` and `paste()` together. `legend()` always seems to break with a `argument "legend" is missing, with no default`. Apparently `substitute()` can't do new lines, and `mtext()` is a bit... bothersome, compared to the human-readable "bottomright" parameter in `legend()`.

This is as far as I've gotten:

```
paramX = 1234
paramY = 9876

plot.new()

legend("bottomright",
       bty = "n",
       paste("x[max] = ", paramX,
             "\ny[max] = ", paramY)
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
paramX = 1234
paramY = 9876

plot.new()

expr <- vector("expression", 2)
expr[[1]] <- bquote(x[max]==.(paramX))
expr[[2]] <- bquote(y[max]==.(paramY))

legend("bottomright",
       bty = "n",
       legend = expr)
```

Plots this result:

[image: resulting plot]

Relevant documentation: `help("legend"); help("plotmath"); help("bquote")`.

The most difficult part is combining two `bquote` expressions into one expression vector.